# Shooting a moving target from a moving target?

Tags: classical-mechanics

What is the physics of shooting a moving target from a moving target? Bullet turns, target moves, and one have to pre-aim to compensate the difference such as World War II fighter plane. Does it even have a name?

Comment: This is potentially a *vast* area of knowledge. Please refine to a more narrow area that you'd like to explore.

Comment: The https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radiodrome might be of interest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shooting at a moving target, whether or not you are moving, is known as deflection shooting. There is no special name just because the gun platform is also moving.

Besides the obvious things like relative motion, distance and the time of flight of the projectile, you need to know many other things. The attitude of the gun platform and its heave (in a rough sea or a jinking bomber) affect your aim. The airspeed of the plane or wind speed and direction if you are on board a ship or a tank will deflect the path of the projectile. The air pressure, especially the altitude of a plane, will affect the force of the wind, the time of flight and the downward curve due to gravity.

Until computing gunsights came along during WWII, mobile gunnery was a pretty hit-amd-miss affair. Standard Naval and Army practice was to "bracket" your target (fire shots too near and too far) with the first few rounds to get its range, before really letting rip.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Hitting a moving object with another moving object fired from a moving object (i.e., a generalized ballistics problem) requires what is usually called *compensation*, where the projectile's aiming is adjusted to accomodate all the velocities and distances in the setup of the problem.

For long distances (~tens of miles) between the gun and the target, this compensation must include factors that take into account the curvature of the earth, the earth's rotation, and the gyroscopic effects due to the magnitude and direction of the spin of the projectile.

Solving gun ballistics problems in a battleship must be done quickly because the distances are constantly changing. For this reason, 1) electromechanical analog computers were developed in the previous century to properly aim battleship guns without requiring the gunners to do all the trigonometry and algebra in real time, which were used in conjunction with 2) compensation tables, in which specific ballistics problems were set up and partially solved in advance.

Comment: Thank you very much!